# Resolve screen jump when the scrollbar appears

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a modal popup and I'm eliminating the scrollbar with `overflow: hidden` when the modal appears on screen.

I'm using js to calculate the scrollbar width and add a padding to fix the shifting screen when the scrollbar disappears. Something like so:

```
<div className='site-layout-wrapper' style={{'padding-right': modal ? `${scrollbarWidth}px` : '0'}}>
```

The problem is that there is also a slight shift when the scrollbar reappears. How do I solve it?

Comment: Remove the padding?

Comment: I do the padding is 0 when the modal is not on screen, as you can see in the condition above

Comment: I'm not sure what modal/framework you are using since you didn't mention that (it's not plain html/css) but I think you will need to do a page refresh in order for that code to work.

Comment: I'm using react, the elements are rendered when their attributes are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `padding-right` because the scrollbar width depends on the browser. What you can do is set the *container* to `overflow: scroll;` but set the *content* to `overflow: hidden;`. This will cause the scrollbar to always be displayed, but disable scrolling when the modal is open.

Example:

#### In your `.css`:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.site-layout-wrapper.modal-active {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

#### In your `.jsx`:

```
<div className={`site-layout-wrapper ${modal && 'modal-active'}`}>
```

Comment: I don't want the scrollbar to appear behind the modal